# failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found when build script is in child directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build my Dockerfile from a child folder context.

this is my build file in build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
docker build -t app:latest -f ../Dockerfile .
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM app:latest
WORKDIR /app
# This path must exist as it is used as a mount point for testing
# Ensure your app is loading files from this location

FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

# Install Dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

This is my requirements.txt

```
Flask
pandas
requests
gunicorn
pytest
```

When I attempt to run build.sh within the scripts folder I get this error

```
#8 ERROR: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
------
 > [stage-1 4/7] COPY requirements.txt .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

When I just do the docker build command in the command line in the app directory I will do this:

```
docker build -t app:latest -f Dockerfile .
```

This will work, however going into the child directory and attempting to build it using the bash script will fail with the requirements.txt caching issue.

How do I successfully build my docker container from the child folder?

[image: My File Structure]

Answer (score 1):

The `docker build` command takes a path to a *context directory*

```bash
docker build [... options ...] .
#                              ^ this path
```

When the Dockerfile `COPY requirements.txt .` it is always relative to the path at the end of the `docker build` command.  It doesn't matter where the `Dockerfile` itself is physically located.

If you want to build an image from a parent directory, where the `Dockerfile` is located in that parent directory, you need to specify the path.  If the Dockerfile is named `Dockerfile` and is in the root of the context directory (the standard recommended location) then you do not need a `docker build -f` option.

```bash
cd $HOME/testing-docker
docker build -t app .

cd $HOME/testing-docker/scripts
docker build -t app ..
#                   ^^ build the parent directory
#                      but no -f option
#                      the Dockerfile is in the default place

# Any way to specify the path will work
cd
docker build -t app $HOME/testing-docker
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix my problem by doing the build as docker build -t app:latest -f ../Dockerfile ..